# Is it possible to get the status of the Shader Compilation with python?

Tags: python, materials, shaders

I'm wondering if there is any API to configure and get when the shader compilation is ready.

It would be useful to me to see when I add a material via script, when this is actually compiling and finished compiling

I have the feeling that this is not possible, but I wanted to get rid of this doubt

Comment: Assuming Blender 2.8 or 2.9?

Comment: 2.9 or newer is better